# Wix catch Windows Installer error message by INSTALLUILEVEL_FULL mode

Tags: windows, installation, wix

How can I catch the default error message of windows installer? It look like silent mode, have no any message are showed.
For example, when another msi is in progress, installer will show error message with error code 1500: "Another installation is in progress. You must complete that installation before continuing this one.", I dont want to show it in this situations, just exit installer.
Plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

The "Another installation is in progress" error is shown automatically by Windows Installer. It's an internal error, it's not managed by your package. So you cannot control it.

This is also the case for most installation errors. You cannot catch them or handle them in a custom way. The best you can do is try to avoid them, for example by not launching another MSI during the installation.

If you need to install other packages with your installer, you can try adding them as prerequisites.